# Posterior and prior distributions

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> (a) Let $p$ ⇠ $Beta(a, b)$, where a and b are positive real numbers. Find $E(p^2(1−p)^2)$.
>
> Two teams, A and B, have an upcoming match. They will play ***five*** games and the
>   winner will be declared to be the team that wins the majority of games. Given $p$, the outcomes of games are independent, with probability $p$ of team $A$ winning and $1 − p$ of team $B$ winning. But you don’t know $p$, so you decide to model it as an r.v., with $p$ ⇠ $Unif(0, 1)$ a priori (before you have observed any data).
>   To learn more about $p$, you look through the historical records of previous games between these two teams, and find that the previous outcomes were, in chronological order, $AAABBAABAB$.
>
> (b) Does your posterior distribution for $p$, given the historical record of games between $A$ and $B$, depend on the specific order of outcomes or only on the fact that $A$ won exactly $6$ of the $10$ games on record? Explain.
>
> (c) Find the posterior distribution for $p$, given the historical data.
>   The posterior distribution for $p$ from (c) becomes your new prior distribution, and the match is about to begin!
>
> (d) Conditional on $p$, is the indicator of $A$ winning the first game of the match positively correlated with, uncorrelated with, or negatively correlated of the indicator of A winning the second game of the match? What about if we only condition on the historical data?
>
> (e) Given the historical data, what is the expected value for the probability that the match is not yet decided when going into the fifth game (viewing this probability as an r.v. rather than a number, to reflect our uncertainty about it)?

$P(I_n=1|p)=p$, hist.data|p~Binom (10,p)

a) $E(p^2(1−p)^2)=E(p^2[1+p^2-2p])=E(2p^2-2p^3)=2E(p^2)-2E(p^3)$;

$E[p^2]=\int_{0}^{1} p^{a+1}(1-p)^{b-1}/B(a,b)dx=\frac{B(a+2;b)}{B(a,b)}=\frac{a(a+1)}{(a+b+1)(a+b)}$

$E[p^3]=B(a+3;b)/B(a;b)=\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)}{(a+b+2)(a+b+1)(a+b)}$; from here it can be computed.

b) It does not depend on order.

c) I can't come up with anything but: $P(p|I_n=i)=P(I_n=i|p)f(p)/P(I_n=i)=p/(p+1-p)=p$;  $p \in (0,1)$

d) Uncorreleted, since based on the answer of @heropup and since $I_{A1}$ is independent of $I_{A2}$ given $p$ $$\operatorname{E}[I_{A1} I_{A2} \mid p] - \operatorname{E}[I_{A1} \mid p]\operatorname{E}[I_{A2} \mid p]=0$$

e)

Is it wrong? If no, please, hep to find e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, the computation can be made **substantially** simpler by recalling that 
$$\begin{align*}\operatorname{E}[g(P)] &= \int_{p=0}^1 g(p) f_P(p) \, dp \\
&= \int_{p=0}^1 p^2 (1 - p)^2 \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} p^{a-1} (1-p)^{b-1} \, dp \\
&= \frac{(a+1)(a)(b+1)(b)}{(a+b+3)(a+b+2)(a+b+1)(a+b)}\int_{p=0}^1 \frac{\Gamma((a+2)+(b+2))}{\Gamma(a+2)\Gamma(b+2)} p^{a+1} (1-p)^{b+1} \, dp \\
&= \frac{(a+1)(a)(b+1)(b)}{(a+b+3)(a+b+2)(a+b+1)(a+b)}. \end{align*}$$  Your own calculation is not correct because you should have had a term of order $p^4$, which you do not.

In part (b), you do not explain why the order of the historical games does not matter.  You simply claim they do not, but **why?**

In part (c), your answer is unintelligible as you do not define your notation.  It's also wrong.

In part (d), your answer suggests that you have not understood what the question is asking for.  There are two parts:  the first part is to define the random variables $$I_{Ai} \mid p = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{A wins game $i$ given $p$} \\ 0, & \text{A loses game $i$ given $p$} \end{cases}$$ for $i = 1, 2$.  Then it asks you to compute $$\operatorname{E}[I_{A1} I_{A2} \mid p] - \operatorname{E}[I_{A1} \mid p]\operatorname{E}[I_{A2} \mid p].$$  The second part asks if the condition is not for a fixed $p$ but instead on the historical data.

Comment: In fact, I know that it is wrong. However, what I don't know is how to define the information recieved from observing historcial data.

Comment: Ok... I got it.